# How to add buttons next to a Swiftui navigation link

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I am making a simple checklist app that allows you to see more detailed information about items. I would like to be able to tap the checkbox (the circle button) to remove the item or click on the rest of the navigation link to enter that separate page. Here is my code for the list that's embedded in a navigation view:

```
List {
  ForEach(fruitIds, id: \.self) { fruitId in
    HStack {
      Button {
        fruitIds.removeLast()
        fruits.remove(at: fruitId)
      } label: {
        Image(systemName: "circle")
          .imageScale(.large)
          .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
      }
      NavigationLink(destination: Text(fruits[fruitId])) {
        Text(fruits[fruitId])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, pressing either the button or the navigation link sends you to the other screen, deletes the item, which then sends you back to the list.

I have these 2 arrays declared btw

```
@State var fruits: [String] = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "peach"]
@State var fruitIds: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Also, I'm very new to Swift, and there's definitely a better way to do this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am taking the answer to your button question from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70287828/7129318), so please give credit there. It is also possible to use a `Button` with a programmatically triggered `NavigationLink` in a `.background()` as the `NavigationLink`. That can be tricky to make it look stock, and this solution does what you want. This  However, you also asked about the list, and that question is very important to understand.

First, if at all possible, avoid using `id: \.self` in a `List`, `ForEach`, etc. The reason is it is very fragile, and will come back to bite you when you try to delete or move items, or if you have two of the "same" items in the list. You really should be using an identifiable struct for this. For this answer, I am using:

```
struct Fruit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var type: String
    // var color: Color, etc.
}
```

The view then becomes:

```
struct FruitListView: View {
    
    //  This array can have duplicate fruits and the ForEach is unaffected as the id's are different.
    @State var fruits: [Fruit] = [Fruit(type: "apple"),
                                  Fruit(type: "orange"),
                                  Fruit(type: "orange"),
                                  Fruit(type: "banana"),
                                  Fruit(type: "banana"),
                                  Fruit(type: "peach")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            // Since Fruit conforms to Identifiable, you do not need id:
            ForEach(fruits) { fruit in
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        fruits.removeAll(where: { $0.id == fruit.id })
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // This is necessary to capture the click
                    .frame(width: 40)
                    // .contentShape makes a larger tap area to take up the height of the row.
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    // You can use fruit directly as it is a Fruit and an element of fruits
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(fruit.type)) {
                        Text(fruit.type)
                    }
                }
            }
            // This is a standard delete. Try implementing it in your code. You will likely get a crash.
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
    }
    
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
                fruits.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, 2 questions. 1: the fruits.removeLast would remove the last item on the list, rather than the item that you press on. I’m not at my laptop right now so I loaded it into swift playgrounds and this appears to be the behavior. 2: When I load this into swift playgrounds the navigation links are greyed out, this may be something thats up with swift playgrounds, and I can see if it works when I get back to my laptop, but I’ve never had any issues with swift playgrounds in the past.

Comment: 1. Yes, fruits.removeLast removes the last item. That is why I added the `.onDelete`. 2. The grayed out links are because the view is not imbedded in a `NavigationView`. The view above assumes that it is not the first view and that some parent view contains the `NavigationView`.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. How would I have the checkbox remove the item that it is attached to, in the same way, my original list behaved?

Comment: The answer is updated.