# Unexpected behavior with SwiftUI NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

With following code, if I click any "label", it will take me to "todo" view, but I need to click "back" twice in order to return to the original view.
The problem does not happen if I make any of the following changes

- remove HStack
- remove List
- replace List with ScrollView

It's almost like when clicking on a label, the click event gets applied to all `NavigationLink` in the `HStack`.
Anyone understand what's going on under the hood?

```swift
struct Sample : View {
    var body : some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("todo")
                    }
                    label: {
                        Text("label")
                    }
                    
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("todo")
                    }
                    label: {
                        Text("label")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The List turns the whole row to a single button. This is a known behavior.

Comment: I see. What's the best way to have multiple buttons per row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72061179/7129318

Comment: Use a ScrollView with a LazyVStack. List/Form are very handy and have a lot of built in behavior but they are meant to look and behave like Apple apps look and behave.

Comment: I've found you can have multiple buttons within a single list row if you give them a `.buttonStyle(.plain)`, which overrides `List`'s internal button style. You do also lose some of the formatting that style provides. `NavigationLink`s are effectivly buttons with additional behaviour, so the same should apply…